# error: [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, storyboard

i am use storyboard to build a custom keyboard UI. app working well,but i have a constraints error as below. somebody can tell me how could i fix it?

this error seems like cause by the storyboard, but i cant tell what exactly it is, maybe i should not force to set the height and width contraints.

platform info
xcode: Version 14.3 (14E222b)
language: swift

```
2023-04-22 15:44:03.092625+0800 bopomofoKeyboard[1983:45953] Failed to inherit CoreMedia permissions from 870: (null)
2023-04-22 15:44:03.167932+0800 bopomofoKeyboard[1983:45757] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000010e0870 UIView:0x7fcdf830a9a0.width == 414   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000010e45f0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' UIView:0x7fcdf830a9a0.width == 393   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000010e0870 UIView:0x7fcdf830a9a0.width == 414   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

and my code like this

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        // Perform custom UI setup here
        // disable autoresize
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
          if(preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation.isPortrait)  {
                       //set row landscape protrait height
                        RowA0.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 45).isActive = true
                        RowA1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
                        RowA2.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
                        RowA3.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
                        RowA4.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 45).isActive = true
                        RowB1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
                        RowB2.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
                        RowB3.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
                        RowC1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
                        RowC2.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
                        ThirdKeyboardButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
                        ShiftButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
                        //change keyboard protrait hight
                         let heightconstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.view as Any,attribute: .height,relatedBy: .equal,toItem: nil,attribute: .notAnAttribute,multiplier: 0.0,
                                                                   constant: 258) // Set custom height here
                                                                   self.view.addConstraint(heightconstraint)
                         //change keyboard protrait width
                          let widthconstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.view as Any,attribute: .width,relatedBy: .equal,toItem: nil,attribute: .notAnAttribute,multiplier: 0.0,
                                                                   constant: 414) // Set custom width here
                                                                   self.view.addConstraint(widthconstraint)
           }
           if(preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation.isLandscape) {
                      //set row landscape landscape height
                        RowA0.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
                        RowA1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
                        RowA2.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
                        RowA3.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
                        RowA4.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
                        RowB1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
                        RowB2.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
                        RowB3.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
                        RowC1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
                        RowC2.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
                        ThirdKeyboardButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
                        ShiftButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
                       //change keyboard landscape hight
                         let heightconstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.view as Any,attribute: .height,relatedBy: .equal,toItem: nil,attribute: .notAnAttribute,multiplier: 0.0,
                                                                   constant: 170) // Set custom height here
                                                                   self.view.addConstraint(heightconstraint)
                         //change keyboard landscape width
                          let widthconstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.view as Any,attribute: .width,relatedBy: .equal,toItem: nil,attribute: .notAnAttribute,multiplier: 0.0,
                                                                   constant: 808) // Set custom width here
                                                                   self.view.addConstraint(widthconstraint)
           }
```

and i have a storyboard too

[image]

Comment: You seem to be assuming the device is 414 points wide as you set an explicit width constraint at that size. The iPhone 6/7/8 plus devices have a width of 414 points. The constraint error shows a conflicting width of 393 points. That is the width of an iPhone 14 pro. You need to make your keyboard and the keys support quite a wide range of widths for different device types (especially if you need to support iPad).

Comment: i got it, sure, i just swith to iphone 14 developing now, thx, let me try